# Proof verification of the closure of a union is the union of closures

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

everyone. Here is a proof I wrote demonstrating $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$. I noticed in proofs of this nature, I often overlook small but important details. Is there anything that I should add?

Let $L=L_A\cup L_B$, where $L_A$ and $L_B$ are the limit points of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $x\in\overline{A\cup B}$, then $x\in\overline{A\cup B}\rightarrow x\in(A\cup B)\cup L\rightarrow x\in(A\cup B)\cup(L_A\cup L_B)\rightarrow$
$x\in(A\cup L_A)\cup(B\cup L_B)\rightarrow x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$. Thus, $ \overline{A\cup B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$, then $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\rightarrow x\in(A\cup L_A)\cup(B\cup L_B)x\in(A\cup B)\cup(L_A\cup L_B)\rightarrow$
$x\in(A\cup B)\cup L\rightarrow x\in\overline{A\cup B}$. Thus, $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$.

Since $\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$ and $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$, we conclude $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

Comment: How do you know that for $L := L_{A\cup B}$, $L = L_A \cup L_B$?

Comment: I don't, it was just an assumption. Our book defines a closure as $\overline{A}=A\cup L$, where A is a set and L is its limit points. I thought defining it in such a way would get around the issue of A or B not having limit points.

Comment: Yes, so by this definition, $\overline{A\cup B} = (A\cup B) \cup (L_{A \cup B})$ (using your notation with the L-subscript denoting the limit points of the set). At some point you should verify that $L_{A \cup B} = L_A \cup L_B$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think a first "proof jr." of this "chasing the element" style (claim its in left side, show its in right side, then do the reverse) would suffice?